# How to get classes interact with one another

Tags: ruby

I have classes person, dogs, cats, and fishes, and I need them to interact. More specifically, I need the Person class to buy an instance of the dog class, or name an instance of the cat class, etc.

How do I do that? My variables are class variables, they are out of scope to use in another class. I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Where to start: `attr_accessor`

Comment: Show us what you've got so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have person.rb:

```
Class Person
 .......
end
```

and you have dog.rb:

```
class Dog
 ........
end
```

If you want to access to Dog class inside Person you have to include it. 
That means your dog.rb would be:

```
require 'dog'

class Person
  def my_method
    dog = Dog.new()
  end
end
```

> require 'name_of_file_with_class'

This is just a pure example how to make it accessible, furthermore it depends on what exactly do you want.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed. The require part is what i was missing. Much appreciated